# Adding Functionality to C# Structures

Tags: c#, events, design-patterns, data-structures, extension-methods

I'm trying to find how to add functionality to C# structures, and in a more elegant way than just wrapping them in entirely new classes. An extension method just isn't as powerful as an override, and most definitely cannot give a struct event firing/handling capabilities either.

The specific problem I'm currently facing however is detecting and reacting to changes in a Vector2 structure's members. This is only an internal requirement though, so users of my library should be able to use/perceive only Vector2 structures when interacting with it (while still setting off internal events).

---

**Generally, how can I extend C# structures other than by extension methods or encapsulation?**

**Specifically, how can I extend the Vector2 structure to support event firing/handling?**

Comment: I would say you need a class, not a struct

Comment: Like devundef said. Structures in C# are nothing more than lightweight way to keep related data together. If you need more logic and extensibility, then use class.

Comment: @Euphoric: why do you say that structures in C# are "nothing more than lightweight way to keep related data together"? It is true that a struct cannot inherit another, but you can have methods on structs. And why do you say they are "lightweight"?

Comment: @Griffin: I suppose you are using an *existing* Vector2 struct, and that you cannot modify its code, right?

Comment: @PaoloTedesco They aren't necessarily lightweight, but they almost always should be. Otherwise passing them to methods or assigning them gets increasingly heavy and even if it's "naturally" a struct, you're likely better off using a class - the extent to which this is true increasing with the size of the struct.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: that was clear to me (structs being passed by value), but I was wondering if they have some feature that makes them "intrinsically" lightweight :)

Comment: @PaoloTedesco not a thing inherently, but I read Euphoric's comment as about purpose rather than implementation. If it's not lightweight it's probably not a purpose that matches, though there are some interop cases that call for very large structs.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: I see, I probably misinterpreted the comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Generally, how can I extend C# structures other than by extension
>   methods or encapsulation?

The only way is to create extension methods or use encapsulation.

> Specifically, how can I extend the Vector2 structure to support event
>   firing/handling?

As I said previously you can use encapsulation and **create a class**. So use this code:

```
public class ExtendedVector2 {
    public Vector2 Vector{
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ExtendedVector2(float value){
        Vector = new Vector2(value);
    }   

    public ExtendedVector2(float x, float y){
        Vector = new Vector2(x, y);
    }
}
```

Then you can add interfaces, methods and events.

**EDIT :**

> But how would I detect if X or Y changes? Say the user "gets" the
>   Vector, and then sets one of its members (X or Y). I could add event
>   firing for when the Vector as a whole is set, but not when one of it's
>   members are set after a 'get.' Keep in mind that I don't want to force
>   the user to use a new vector class in order to interact with my
>   library. I don't even want him/her to have to know that a new vector
>   class is being used internally.

Firstly if you want to mask completely that internally is used a structure of type `Vector2` you should rewrite all methods in this way:

```
public class ExtendedVector2 {
    //...
    private Vector2 _vector2;  

    //mask X and Y values of Vector2 structure 
    public float X{
        set{ _vector2.X = value; }
        get{ return _vector2.X; }
    }

    public float Y{
        set{ _vector2.Y = value; }
        get{ return _vector2.Y; }
    } 

    //example to mask a method of Vector2 structure 
    public static float Dot(ExtendedVector2 value1, ExtendedVector2 value2){
        return Vector.Dot(value1, value2);
    }

    //override the cast to Vector2
    public static implicit operator Vector2(ExtendedVector2 value) //I'd make it implicit because I'd think to it like an upcast
    {
        return new Vector2(value.X, value.Y);
    }
}
```

For more info [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196385.aspx).

Now it's simple if you want to create an event that is fired when one members changes.
I'd create a costumized EventArgs. Let's write some code:

```
//use the convention of eventName+EventArgs
class MemberChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public readonly float LastValue{
        get;
        set;
    }
    public readonly float NewValue{
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MemberChangedEventArgs(float LastValue, float NewValue)
    {
        this.LastValue = LastValue;
        this.NewValue = NewValue;
    }
}
```

Then you can write your own event:

```
public class ExtendedVector2 {
    private Vector2 _vector2;  

    public float X{
         set{                  
             if(_vector2.X != value)           
               OnMemberXChanged(new MemberChangedEventArgs(_vector2.X, value));

             _vector2.X = value;   
         }
         get{ return _vector2.X; }
    }

    public float Y{
         set{ 
             if(_vector2.Y != value)
               OnMemberYChanged(new MemberChangedEventArgs(_vector2.Y, value));

             _vector2.Y = value;                    
         }
         get{ return _vector2.Y; }
    }        

    public event EventHandler<MemberChangedEventArgs> MemberXChanged;
    public event EventHandler<MemberChangedEventArgs> MemberYChanged;

    public ExtendedVector2(float value){
        Vector = new Vector2(value);
    }   

    public ExtendedVector2(float x, float y){
        Vector = new Vector2(x, y);
    }

    private virtual void OnMemberXChanged(MemberChangedEventArgs e){
        if(MemberXChanged != null)
           MemberXChanged(this, e);
    }

    private virtual void OnMemberYChanged(MemberChangedEventArgs e){
        if(MemberYChanged != null)
           MemberYChanged(this, e);
    }
    //... 

    //here mask the Vector2 structure using the previous solution
}
```

Comment: But how would I detect if X or Y changes? Say the user "gets" the Vector, and then sets one of its members (X or Y). I could add event firing for when the Vector as a whole is set, but not when one of it's members are set after a 'get.' Keep in mind that I don't want to force the user to use a new vector class in order to interact with my library. I don't even want him/her to have to know that a new vector class is being used internally.