# INotifyPropertyChanged in c# structures

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

Hello I have the following code:

```
public struct zoomInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public float zoom;
    public float translateX;
    public float translateY;
    private int level;

    public int zoomLevel 
    { 
        get { return level; }
        set { 
            level = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("zoomLevel");
        }
    }

    //region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    //endregion

};
```

When I bind this to a control.. it is not working. PropertyChangedEventHandler is always null.. But when I change this to class instead of struct, PropertyChangedEventHandler is not null and binding works perfectly. So the question is, does INotifyPropertyChanged only works on classes?

Comment: structs are always passed by value. that does not play well with events in general. [consider this](http://kosiara87.blogspot.co.at/2011/11/cnever-place-event-inside-struct-c.html), [and this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12173723/1132334)

Comment: So I guess the accepted answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065954/structs-and-inotifypropertychanged is a misinformation

Comment: Consider the boxing required to support  [structures that implements interfaces](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2005/10/05/c-structs-and-interface/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in a struct, but you should never do that, because semantics of structs do not play well (I'd say at all) with this interface, and events in general. Consider this:

```
struct EventStruct : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private string _property;

    public string Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set
        {
            _property = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now we just subscribe to event and change a property:

```
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var s = new EventStruct();
        s.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
        s.Property = "test";
        Console.ReadKey();
    }        

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.PropertyName + " changed");
    }        
}
```

Output is "Property changed". So you cannot say that structs and events do not work at all (or that `INotifyPropertyChanged` doesn't work with structs). It works, kind of, until you try to pass that struct anywhere:

```
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var s = new EventStruct();            
        Bind(s);
        s.Property = "test";
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Bind(INotifyPropertyChanged item) {
        // this is not the same instance of EventStruct,
        // it's a copy, and event will never be fired on this copy
        item.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.PropertyName + " changed");
    }        
}
```

Passing struct to `Bind` method as `INotifyPropertyChanged` boxes that struct, which makes a copy, so you subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event using one instance of `EventStruct` (a copy), but event is fired on another instance of the struct. So event subscriber list is empty on that instance where event is actually fired. Same happens if you just pass struct and not interface (in this case struct is copied because passed by value):

```
static void Bind(EventStruct item) {
    item.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
}
```

If you will pass by reference, it will work again:

```
static void Bind(ref EventStruct item) {
    item.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
}
```

For that reason you should never implement events on structs, at least no use case comes to my mind where this can be useful and not lead into troubles.

Comment: WinForms data binding works with `object` (hence will always work with boxed struct), so passing by reference is not even an option.

Comment: @IvanStoev sure, only option is just not do this. Ref example is just for explanation of behavior, not as a workaround.